# How to overcome in-app-purchase limitations to achieve following business case?

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

We have the following use case as per our business model:

A user can add multiple GPS devices and add a plan for each device. Each plan and add-on is basically a subscription that the user needs to purchase. Users can register multiple devices therefore users can select multiple subscription plans for different devices. 
After registering user can upgrade, downgrade, pause and cancel the subscription for individual devices separately. Also, users can update auto-renewal subscriptions to non-renewal and vice versa.

Currently, we already have an existing system using credit cards which are published on Android, iOS and web platforms. We are using credit cards for payments and handling all needed scenarios on the backend. But for our new upgraded iOS app, we have been forced to implement in-app purchase where we have the following limitations which are blocking us to fulfil our current requirements:

- Users cannot subscribe to one auto-renewal plan for multiple times.
- Users cannot subscribe to multiple plans in a single transaction.
- Users cannot upgrade or downgrade multiple subscriptions in a single transaction.
- Auto-renewal to non-renewal subscription is not possible
- Non-renewal subscription to auto-renewal subscription is not possible
- Pause subscription feature is not provided by in-app purchase
- Subscription cancellation is only allowed via the App Store and no utility method is provided by IAP

**Does anybody have any idea to overcome the above limitations or any workarounds? Or the App Store team can allow us without in-app purchases?**

We have explained these use cases to the App Store team but still, they have mandated the use of in-app-purchase. Also, we have removed the complete payment flow from our app but they are still not approving the app citing that the multi-platform services clause “The paid digital content, services, or subscriptions included in or accessed by your app must be available for purchase using in-app purchase.”

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecB0l.png